# Is there a connection between graph theory and many worlds QM

Tags: graph-theory, quantum-mechanics

Obligatory disclaimer that this is my first post and first contact with the community so please redirect me to better channels if these types of questions are not for this forum.

So I was just naively wondering about how you could label the different states of the universe as `U1, U2, …` in the many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics, and construct a directed graph on these states as vertices and the edges being the possible transformations between these states.

Do we know anything about this graph? Is a model like this even considered when discussing many worlds?

Looking for guidance about some further topics and resources that I can explore.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So the concept of ruliad space answers my question
https://www.wolframphysics.org/bulletins/2020/06/exploring-rulial-space-the-case-of-turing-machines/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).